# Responsive css designs on high resolution mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I am using `max-width: 768px` to change looks on my website. But there are many high resolution devices on market (4K Mobile phones etc). How can I detect them? should I use orientation portrait? Or can I specify a aspect ratio as a code? What is the best way to catch all devices for responsive web design?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options for this problem:
Within your media query you can test for the device `width`, resolution (`pixel density`), `orientation`, `aspect ratio`, `pointer` option and many more. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries for a full list of options.
It is recommended to support your implementation by feature and not by environment. For example you can target `dark/light` mode or if a device supports `hover` events instead of checking for `phone`, `tablet`, `desktop`, `tv`, `gaming console` …
Also you can combine different CSS units like `em`, `vmin`, `vh`, `vh`, `%` to get relative measurements.
This in combination with CSS `grid` can already solve many problems without defining a media query.
Of course in the end you probably still end up with *some* media queries. For that I recommend to pick 2-4 common screen sizes even though this is no guarantee that it will cover *all* devices.

I can also recommend you these episodes from The CSS Podcast

- [@rules](https://thecsspodcast.libsyn.com/031-rules)
- [Preference Media Queries](https://thecsspodcast.libsyn.com/033-preference-media)